# How do you run `yield next` inside a promise or callback?

Tags: javascript, generator, koa, koa-router

I'm stuck writing an authentication router for a koa app.

I have a module that gets data from the DB then compares it to the request. I want to only run `yield next` if the authentication passes.

The problem is that the module that communicates with the DB returns a promise and if I try to run `yield next` inside that promise I get an error. Either `SyntaxError: Unexpected strict mode reserved word` or `SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier` depending on whether or not strict mode is used.

Here's a simplified example:

```
var authenticate = require('authenticate-signature');

// authRouter is an instance of koa-router
authRouter.get('*', function *(next) {
  var auth = authenticate(this.req);

  auth.then(function() {
    yield next;
  }, function() {
    throw new Error('Authentication failed');
  })
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think I figured it out.

The promise needs to be yielded which will pause the function until the promise has been resolved then continue.

```
var authenticate = require('authenticate-signature');

// authRouter is an instance of koa-router
authRouter.get('*', function *(next) {
  var authPassed = false;

  yield authenticate(this.req).then(function() {
    authPassed = true;
  }, function() {
    throw new Error('Authentication failed');
  })

  if (authPassed)  {
   yield next;
  }
});
```

This seems to work, but I'll update this if I run into any more problems.